# Running Job On Airflow Based On Webrequest

Tags: python, airflow

I wanted to know if airflow tasks can be executed upon getting a request over HTTP. I am not interested in the scheduling part of Airflow. I just want to use it as a substitute for Celery.

So an example operation would be something like this.

1. User submits a form requesting for some report.
2. Backend receives the request and sends the user a notification that the request has been received.
3. The backend then schedules a job using Airflow to run immediately.
4. Airflow then executes a series of tasks associated with a DAG. For example, pull data from redshift first, pull data from MySQL, make some operations on the two result sets, combine them and then upload the results to Amazon S3, send an email.

From whatever I read online, you can run airflow jobs by executing `airflow ...` on the command line. I was wondering if there is a python api which can execute the same thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! What was your solution for this after all? I am kind of facing the same problem

Comment: I did not use AirFlow in the end since I couldn't figure out the solution. I ended up using Celery instead.

Comment: this is interesting, how many calls do you have in each hour? I think if the number is high, maybe it's not good to use airflow

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Airflow REST API Plugin](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin) would help you out here. Once you have followed the instructions for installing the plugin you would just need to hit the following url: `http://{HOST}:{PORT}/admin/rest_api/api/v1.0/trigger_dag?dag_id={dag_id}&run_id={run_id}&conf={url_encoded_json_parameters}`, replacing dag_id with the id of your dag, either omitting run_id or specify a unique id, and passing a url encoded json for conf (with any of the parameters you need in the triggered dag).

Here is an example JavaScript function that uses jQuery to call the Airflow api:

```
function triggerDag(dagId, dagParameters){
    var urlEncodedParameters = encodeURIComponent(dagParameters);
    var dagRunUrl = "http://airflow:8080/admin/rest_api/api/v1.0/trigger_dag?dag_id="+dagId+"&conf="+urlEncodedParameters;
    $.ajax({
        url: dagRunUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log('Successfully started the dag');
        },
        error: function(e){
           console.log('Failed to start the dag');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This was correct at the time, but I think you should mention now the experimental API.

Answer (score 18):

A new option in airflow is the *experimental*, but built-in, API endpoint in the more recent builds of 1.7 and 1.8. This allows you to run a REST service on your airflow server to listen to a port and accept cli jobs.

I only have limited experience myself, but I have run test dags with success. Per the docs:

`/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs` creates a dag_run for a given dag id (POST).

That will schedule an immediate run of whatever dag you want to run. It does still use the scheduler, though, waiting for a heartbeat to see that dag is running and pass tasks to the worker. This is exactly the same behavior as the CLI, though, so I still believe it fits your use-case.

Documentation on how to configure it is available here: https://airflow.apache.org/api.html

There are some simple example clients in the github, too, under airflow/api/clients

Comment: In the latest version they changed the auth_backend variable from default to deny_all in the airflow.cfg. Change it to default for testing purposes.

Answer (score 6):

You should look at [Airflow HTTP Sensor](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_http_operator.py) for your needs. You can use this to trigger a dag.

Comment: The link response of github informed: 404 Not Found

Answer (score 4):

Airflow's experimental REST API interface can be used for this purpose.

Following request will trigger a DAG:

```
curl -X POST \
    http://<HOST>:8080/api/experimental/dags/process_data/dag_runs \
    -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"conf":"{\"START_DATE\":\"2018-06-01 03:00:00\", \"STOP_DATE\":\"2018-06-01 23:00:00\"}'
```

Following request retrieves a list of Dag Runs for a specific DAG ID:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://<HOST>:8080/api/experimental/dags/process_data/dag_runs
```

For the GET API to work set `rbac` flag to `True` at `airflow.cfg`.

Following are the list of APIs available: [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py) & [there](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www_rbac/api/experimental/endpoints.py).

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** stable Airflow REST API released:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html

Almost everything stays the same, except API URL change.
Also "conf" is now required to be an object, so I added additional wrapping:

```
 def trigger_dag_v2(self, dag_id, run_id=None, conf=None, execution_date=None):
    endpoint = '/api/v1/dags/{}/dagRuns'.format(dag_id)
    url = urljoin(self._api_base_url, endpoint)
    data = self._request(url, method='POST',
                         json={
                             "run_id": run_id,
                             "conf": {'conf': json.dumps(event)},
                             "execution_date": execution_date,
                         })
    return data['message']
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Airflow has REST API (currently experimental) - available here:
https://airflow.apache.org/api.html#endpoints

If you do not want to install plugins as suggested in other answers - here is code how you can do it directly with the API:

```
def trigger_dag(self, dag_id, run_id=None, conf=None, execution_date=None):
    endpoint = '/api/experimental/dags/{}/dag_runs'.format(dag_id)
    url = urljoin(self._api_base_url, endpoint)
    data = self._request(url, method='POST',
                         json={
                             "run_id": run_id,
                             "conf": conf,
                             "execution_date": execution_date,
                         })
    return data['message']
```

More examples working with airflow API in python are available here:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/client/json_client.py

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while trying to do the same, after further investigation, I switch to ArgoEvents. It is basically the same but based on event-driven flows so it is much more suitable for this use case.
Link:
https://argoproj.github.io/argo

Comment: Your answer reads as advertisement and not solving the problem stated by OP. "more suitable" doesn't cover the payload of information in your answer so please elaborate on e.g. differences or shortcuts.. what ever comes to mind that comes close in answering the question raised. Otherwise its merely a comment if not advertisement. End of Review. Finish the SO tour! Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Airflow now has support for [stable REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run). Using stable REST API, you can trigger DAG as:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/unpublished/dagRuns' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--data-raw '{
    "dag_run_id": "dag_run_1",
    "conf": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}'
```